# Illustrate mean and standard deviation in ggplot2 density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, kernel-density

I'm trying to construct a plot where I plot normally distributed variables showing their mean on the x-axis and the standard deviation (SD) on the y-axis. Kinda like a density plot, but instead of having the density on the y-axis I want to have the SD (value).

I'm working with the data below,

```
set.seed(1)
mu1 <- rnorm(10^5, mean = 1, sd = 1)
mu3 <- rnorm(10^5, mean = 3, sd = 2)
```

two normally distributed variables. Here their mean and sd,

```
# install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
require(tidyverse)
tibble(mu1, mu3) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean, sd))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    mu1_mean mu3_mean    mu1_sd   mu3_sd
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 0.9993454 3.000825 0.9982848 1.998234
```

I've played around with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), and other [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) packages, to get closer to what I want. I've also tried copying [this function](http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.com/2014/02/boxplot-with-mean-and-standard.html) from a box-plot doing something similar, having succeeded yet.

Here is my start,

```
tibble(mu1, mu3) %>% gather() %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x = value, colour = key)) + 
  labs(x = 'mean', y = 'currently density, but I would like sd')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Do you have an example of the plot you have in mind? (Could be a drawing). What message should your plot convey?

Comment: I more or less want what's in the plot you see, but I want the standard deviation on the y-axis instead of the density. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really to me, as the sd is only one number. It doesn't vary along the distribution (as the density does).

Comment: You are plotting the density (which is what `geom_density()` is for) and neither the x- nor the y-axis show the mean or the standard deviation. The boxplot from the example you linked is actually conveying a similar message as the density plot, but in a different way. It, too, does not have mean of standard deviation as one of its axes. I really don't understand your question...

Answer (score 8):

The mean and standard deviation are measured on the x-scale, so you'd need to plot them along the x-axis. The y-axis is the density of points within a given x-interval, and is analogous to the height of the bars in a histogram.

Maybe this will give you something like what you were looking for: The code below adds a horizontal line that spans the standard deviation of each density plot, along with droplines to mark their location on the x-axis. The sd line is located at y-value where the width of the distribution is equal to the standard deviation. If you wish, you could in addition (or instead) fill the region spanned by the standard deviation.

```
library(dplyr)

# Densities
n = 2^10
df = data.frame(x = c(density(foo,n=n)$x, density(bar,n=n)$x),
                y = c(density(foo,n=n)$y, density(bar,n=n)$y),
                group=rep(c("foo","bar"), each=n))

## Mean and SD
msd =  melt(data.frame(foo=foo, bar=bar)) %>% 
         group_by(group=variable) %>% summarise(mean=mean(value), sd=sd(value))

# Find y value (of density) where sd has same width as density
msd$y = unlist(lapply(unique(df$group), function(g) {
  d = df[df$group==g,]
  d$y[which.min(abs(d$x - (msd$mean[msd$group==g] - msd$sd[msd$group==g])))]
}))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line() + labs(x = NULL) +
  geom_segment(data=msd, aes(y=y,yend=y, x=mean - sd, xend=mean + sd), lty="21") +
  geom_point(data=msd, aes(y=y, x=mean)) +
  geom_segment(data=msd, aes(x=mean-sd, xend=mean-sd, y=0, yend=y), alpha=0.5, lty="21") +
  geom_segment(data=msd, aes(x=mean+sd, xend=mean+sd, y=0, yend=y), alpha=0.5, lty="21")
```

[image]

Comment: What is "%>%", it doesn't work for me, it's some kind of pipe? I have never seen it.

Comment: Yes, it's the pipe operator from the `dplyr` package. See the "piping" section of [the `dplyr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html).