# Add shaded standard error curves to geom_density in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density, standard-error

I would like to add shaded standard error curves to `geom_density` using `ggplot2`. My code looks like this:

```
data.plot <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 5),
                                    rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd =2 )), 
                             g = factor(c(rep(1, 100),
                                        rep(2,100))))

ggplot(data.plot, aes(x, linetype = g)) + geom_density()
```

I couldn't find a tutorial or examples to do so. Thank you.

Comment: not entirely sure what you want - maybe look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242947/illustrate-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-ggplot2-density-plot

Comment: Hi @BWilliams , I was aiming to add something like the error bars for histograms

Comment: Is [this plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32630537/8449629) like what you have in mind? If so, the confidence interval has to be obtained via bootstrapping first.

Comment: If you wanna plot calculated error corridors, you might wanna have a look at geom_ribbon: https://www.rstats-tips.net/2016/02/using-geom_ribbon-to-visualize-a-corridor-for-your-data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is with bootstrapping, as mentioned in the comments. I'll use the classic **iris** data, focusing on the density of **Sepal.Length** for each **Species**.

### Generate samples

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


data_frame(bs = 1:1000) %>% group_by(bs) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
                       sample_frac(size = 1, replace = T)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
> # Groups:   bs [1,000]
>       bs               data
>    <int>             <list>
>  1     1 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  2     2 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  3     3 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  4     4 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  5     5 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  6     6 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  7     7 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  8     8 <tibble [150 x 5]>
>  9     9 <tibble [150 x 5]>
> 10    10 <tibble [150 x 5]>
> # ... with 990 more rows
> ```

So I just made 1000 bootstrap replicates of the original data, taking the same number of rows out of each group as its original sample size, with replacement. Now I have to `unnest` to access the data in the nested **data** column.

### Compute within-sample density

```
densities.within <-
data_frame(bs = 1:1000) %>% group_by(bs) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
                       sample_frac(size = 1, replace = T))) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(bs, Species) %>% 
  do(tidy(density(.$Sepal.Length, 
                  from = min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                  to = max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                  n = 128)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 384,000 x 4
> # Groups:   bs, Species [30,000]
>       bs Species        x         y
>    <int>  <fctr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
>  1     1  setosa 4.300000 0.2395786
>  2     1  setosa 4.328346 0.2821128
>  3     1  setosa 4.356693 0.3235939
>  4     1  setosa 4.385039 0.3632449
>  5     1  setosa 4.413386 0.4010378
>  6     1  setosa 4.441732 0.4375189
>  7     1  setosa 4.470079 0.4734727
>  8     1  setosa 4.498425 0.5095333
>  9     1  setosa 4.526772 0.5459280
> 10     1  setosa 4.555118 0.5824587
> # ... with 383,990 more rows
> ```

So we expanded the data to its long form, then took the density of each group's **Sepal.Length** within **Species** within **bs**. We had to supply a manual `from =` and `to =` since the min and max within each bootstrap might differ (and set a lower `n =` than the default 512 just to save time).
To simplify the `S3: density` object that's generated, we use `broom::tidy`. This is the computationally intensive step, so we'll save this object as **densities.within**.

### Summarize densities into quantiles

This results in columns named **x** and **y**, but we'll rename these to match our data. Then we'll figure out: for the densities calculated at each computed possible **Sepal.Length**, what is the lower end of the CI, the median, and the upper end of the CI? We'll use `quantile` to get these specific values of the computed densities.

```
densities.qtiles <-
densities.within %>%
  rename(Sepal.Length = x, dens = y) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
  summarise(q05 = quantile(dens, 0.025),
            q50 = quantile(dens, 0.5),
            q95 = quantile(dens, 0.975))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 384 x 5
> # Groups:   Species [?]
>    Species Sepal.Length        q05       q50       q95
>     <fctr>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
>  1  setosa     4.300000 0.05730022 0.2355335 0.4426299
>  2  setosa     4.328346 0.08177850 0.2734463 0.4970097
>  3  setosa     4.356693 0.09863062 0.3114570 0.5505578
>  4  setosa     4.385039 0.12459033 0.3430645 0.5884523
>  5  setosa     4.413386 0.15049699 0.3705389 0.6207344
>  6  setosa     4.441732 0.17494889 0.4006335 0.6418923
>  7  setosa     4.470079 0.19836510 0.4258006 0.6655006
>  8  setosa     4.498425 0.21106857 0.4555755 0.6971370
>  9  setosa     4.526772 0.23399070 0.4813130 0.7244413
> 10  setosa     4.555118 0.24863090 0.5108057 0.7708114
> # ... with 374 more rows
> ```

### Visualize and compare

```
ggplot(densities.qtiles, aes(Sepal.Length, q50)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species, nrow = 2) +
  geom_histogram(data = iris, 
                 aes(Sepal.Length, ..density..), 
                 colour = "black", fill = "white", 
                 binwidth = 0.25, boundary = 0) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q05, ymax = q95), alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey50") +
  stat_density(data = iris, 
               aes(Sepal.Length, ..density.., color = "raw density"), 
               size = 2, geom = "line") +
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(color = "bootstrapped")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  labs(y = "density") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5,0),
        legend.justification = c(0,0))
```

[image]

I included histogram and density layers for the original data as well for comparison. You can see that the median and raw densities are very close with 1000 bootstrap samples.