# How to add grey shaded area to geom_density to represent standard error?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reflect estimated uncertainty in my geom_density() plots of my coefficient (yes that is a lot of random effect coefficients) by adding in a grey SE line.

But I am struggling to connect or link the grey shaded area to my geom_density plot in ggplot in R. The location of the grey uncertainty interval is wrong.

I am also aware of this answer ([Add shaded standard error curves to geom_density in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908120/add-shaded-standard-error-curves-to-geom-density-in-ggplot2)) but it does not work for me. I have tried changing where I declare my ymin and ymax variables and if I append to the variable name the dataset name or not. I have spent a full day on this problem now...

```
DF <- data.frame(x=rep(1,576))
DF$V <- rnorm(576,mean=2,sd=0.2)
DF$V_se <- rnorm(576,mean=0.2,sd=0.01)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = V, ymin = V - (2*V_se),ymax = V + (2*V_se))) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=0.1, colour = NA)+
  geom_density()
```

The grey line prints in a downward sloping diagonal. Instead I would like the grey ribbon to print and follow along the density curve, to show the degree of uncertainty along the curve. (And I can see that this is a bit odd perhaps give that this is a kernel approximation of the data in the first pace.) [See image link please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGMVn.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: `geom_density` does a transformation of the data, `geom_ribbon` does not. Your standard errors aren't representing the uncertainty in the density. I think the answer you linked has the right idea; you calculate the quantiles from many simulated sets of coefficients. Are the random effects from a Bayesian or frequentist model?

Comment: Thanks for this. Correct. The standard errors are from a Bayesian credible interval: these `random' (group-level) effects are from a Bayesian model. The standard errors are reflecting uncertainty in the coefficients. It's a model with many coefficients (576), so plotting the coefficients like a kernel density and seeing how these coefficients change across time, or between models, is very helpful to me. But maybe you are right: it doesn't make sense to compare a SE of a coefficient (geom_ribbon) with an approximated density of the coefficients (via geom_density).

Comment: If they are based on posteriors, you can just sample from those posteriors directly, calculate a density for each, then calculate quantiles afterwards. I can post some code using `brms` if you're interested.